# Remove extra paragraph breaks in word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-reader, line-spacing

I checked other questions but that were different and many were not answered.

I have a book in pdf which is very large and export to word using Abobe Reader Pro DC, each line in the pdf is copied as a line in word with paragraph breaks in each line.

I also tried some online free converters. They doesn’t work better than Adobe.

What I tried is putting a ‘ mark in front of each paragraph and then replacing each paragraph mark to space. But adding the ‘ mark takes a lot of time. Is there any better way to do it?

A rough example of the text:
“
The benefits of typing is:

1. Having a good understanding of how
   Our finger moves.
2. Having a great understanding of
   How our finger moves.”

See. Here, after point 1, a paragraph mark is added.

I need this example to be made as:
“

The benefits of typing is:

1. Having a good understanding of how our finger moves.
2. Having a great understanding of how our finger moves.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are two or more paragraph marks between each actual paragraph of the text, do the following search and replace:

1. Search`^p^p` change to `^l^l`
2. Search `^p` change to a space
3. Search `^l^l` change to `^p^p`

Edit:

An alternative method:

1. Search`.^p` change to `^l^l`
2. Search `^p` change to a space
3. Search `^l^l` change to `^p`

Note: this method assumes that a period precedes a paragraph marks that actually delimits a paragraph and not a line in the PDF. There may be some false positives and some false negatives, but some proofing should fix that easily enough

Comment: There is no ^p^p. there is only ^p. 

I will update the questions to add more details.

Comment: Is there any other method? I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear where the paragraph marks. Maybe a screencap would be better? See the edit to my answer which suggests an alternative method.

Comment: Ok, that is a very good suggestion. Maybe :^p    ;^p     ?^p     and     -^p  will make it perfect in my case. Thank you very much cybernetic.nomad.